# The type or namespace name 'Specflow_xxx_XUnitAssemblyFixture' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, specflow

After I installed this nuget package in my specflow demo C# .NET Core 3.1 project, I got this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name
> 'Specflow_Demo_XUnitAssemblyFixture' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   Specflow.Demo   ...\Specflow.Demo\Features\LoggedInDiscount.feature.cs\LoggedInDiscount.feature 3   Active

[image]

This is my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.9.22" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.xUnit" Version="3.9.22" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecRun.SpecFlow" Version="3.9.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

After I close all the files in Visual Studio and rebuild, I got another error:

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Whether the `Specflow_Demo_XUnitAssemblyFixture` is the package build in object or it is created by yourself? Besides, about the `SpecFlow` relate package, please make sure it applies to Asp.net core 3.1 Version

Comment: That code is auto generated after I install `SpecRun.SpecFlow` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue with SpecFlow related to this: [Type or namespace [TestNamespace]_XunitAssemblyFixture could not be found](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1825). Are you still able to run your test cases? The above link says its an intellisense only issue.

From a [comment](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1825#issuecomment-578732981) on the GitHub issue discussion:

> The generated assemblyFixture file (e.g.: [TestNamespace]_XunitAssemblyFixture) can be found in the obj folder (obj\Debug\targetframework\xUnit.AssemblyHooks.cs).
> We realized that **this is IntelliSense related "issue"** (IntelliSense of VisualStudio itself, not R#).
> As you all noticed, the build was successful, but the error was still there. This is because the generated code behind file (*.feature.cs) is opened in your editor. If you close them, and build again, the error will disappear.
>
> ...
>
> BTW there is an ongoing [PR](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/pull/1691) which will move the generated files to the obj folder, so this problem will disappear when it'll be merged.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I edited your answer to give a little more information. Answers just containing a link tend to do stale after a while, so I included some quoted text from the discussion and made the URL a link.

Comment: After I close all the files in Visual Studio and rebuild, the initial error no more. But, I got another error which I have just updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look through the types in the referenced nuget packages. None of them uses the naming style that you have there 'Specflow_Demo_XUnitAssemblyFixture' - and none of them has a type with a similar name.

So, as the error says, the type doesnt exist.